# Docker Nginx + NextCloud without domain - just IP

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nextcloud

I am trying to set up docker containers that would utilize NextCloud, Nginx (+ collabora office in afterwards). I am trying to access the docker container in a local network on a Ubuntu server.

Is it possible to set up NextCloud + Nginx without a domain name? I am facing a lot of troubles with reverse proxying and setup - probably becase $host in nginx container returns empty string - I can only provide an IP of a Ubuntu server.

I have tried many docker-compose.yml and nginx.conf setups but still do not get it to work.

This is the sample from Nextcloud Dockerhub, that I believe should work out-of-the-box, but it seems that a domain name is a must:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

volumes:
  nextcloud:
  db:

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=geslo
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=geslo
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud

  app:
    image: nextcloud:fpm
    restart: always
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=geslo
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_HOST=db

  web:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    links:
      - app
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html:ro
```

```
# nginx.conf
worker_processes auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    set_real_ip_from  10.0.0.0/8;
    set_real_ip_from  172.16.0.0/12;
    set_real_ip_from  192.168.0.0/16;
    real_ip_header    X-Real-IP;

    #gzip  on;

    upstream php-handler {
        server app:9000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        # Add headers to serve security related headers
        # Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read into this
        # topic first.
        # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000;
        # includeSubDomains; preload;";
        #
        # WARNING: Only add the preload option once you read about
        # the consequences in https://hstspreload.org/. This option
        # will add the domain to a hardcoded list that is shipped
        # in all major browsers and getting removed from this list
        # could take several months.
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
        add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
        add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
        add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer;

        root /var/www/html;

        location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        # The following 2 rules are only needed for the user_webfinger app.
        # Uncomment it if you're planning to use this app.
        #rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
        #rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json
        # last;

        location = /.well-known/carddav {
            return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
        }
        location = /.well-known/caldav {
            return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
        }

        # set max upload size
        client_max_body_size 10G;
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

        # Enable gzip but do not remove ETag headers
        gzip on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_min_length 256;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private no_last_modified no_etag auth;
        gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json application/ld+json application/manifest+json application/rss+xml application/vnd.geo+json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/bmp image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/cache-manifest text/css text/plain text/vcard text/vnd.rim.location.xloc text/vtt text/x-component text/x-cross-domain-policy;

        # Uncomment if your server is build with the ngx_pagespeed module
        # This module is currently not supported.
        #pagespeed off;

        location / {
            rewrite ^ /index.php$request_uri;
        }

        location ~ ^/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)/ {
            deny all;
        }
        location ~ ^/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/(?:index|remote|public|cron|core/ajax/update|status|ocs/v[12]|updater/.+|ocs-provider/.+)\.php(?:$|/) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            # fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
            #Avoid sending the security headers twice
            fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true;
            fastcgi_param front_controller_active true;
            fastcgi_pass php-handler;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_request_buffering off;
        }

        location ~ ^/(?:updater|ocs-provider)(?:$|/) {
            try_files $uri/ =404;
            index index.php;
        }

        # Adding the cache control header for js and css files
        # Make sure it is BELOW the PHP block
        location ~ \.(?:css|js|woff2?|svg|gif)$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=15778463";
            # Add headers to serve security related headers (It is intended to
            # have those duplicated to the ones above)
            # Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read into
            # this topic first.
            # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000;
            #  includeSubDomains; preload;";
            #
            # WARNING: Only add the preload option once you read about
            # the consequences in https://hstspreload.org/. This option
            # will add the domain to a hardcoded list that is shipped
            # in all major browsers and getting removed from this list
            # could take several months.
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
            add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
            add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
            add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
            add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer;

            # Optional: Don't log access to assets
            access_log off;
        }

        location ~ \.(?:png|html|ttf|ico|jpg|jpeg)$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
            # Optional: Don't log access to other assets
            access_log off;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up NextCloud on docker without any domain, you should be able to access with your server's ip in the browser or localhost if it's on the same computer. You just need to add the different domains or IPs to your nextcloud trusted domain : https://help.nextcloud.com/t/howto-add-a-new-trusted-domain/26

Also, check if your firewall doesn't block the port 80 (iptables -L or ufw status verbose on ubuntu).

Comment: I figured out the problem. It was a problem in nginx.conf file. I will post a complete solution.
Thank you